# LoginPage and MasterDetail Issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.auth

So I'm trying to implement a login with OAuth and the Xamarin.Auth plugin (I'm working in `Xamarin.Forms`, building for ios and android). I successfully followed [this tutorial](http://www.joesauve.com/using-xamarin-auth-with-xamarin-forms/)... on a dummy example. Now I'm try to go for "the real deal" but I'm kind of stuck:

1. My app has a resource dictionary in the `App.xaml` file which doesn't seem to be loaded: In App.xaml.cs, I have

   ```
   public static Action SuccessfulLoginAction
   {
       get
       {
           return new Action(() =>
           {
               _NavPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SampleWithAppResources());
           });
       }
   }
   ```

   Which his invoke in a custom Renderer (android one here, but there is another one for ios):

   ```
   public class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
   {
       public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
       {
           base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

           var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator([...]);

           auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
           {
               App.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();

               if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
               {
                   // The user is authenticated
               }
               else
               {
                   // The user cancelled
               }
           };

           PresentViewController(auth.GetUI(), true, null);
       }
   }
   ```

   SampleWithAppResources is not empty, but appears as a blank page when used in this flow...
2. 2nd problem, my app uses a `MasterDetailPage`. I made the code evolve so it resemble to this:

   ```
   static Root _RootPage;
   public App()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       _RootPage = new Root(){Detail = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage())};
       MainPage = _RootPage;
   } 

   public static Action SuccessfulLoginAction
   {
       get
       {
           return new Action(() =>
           {
               _RootPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new SampleWithAppResources());
           });
       }
   }
   ```

   Which results (once successfully logged in) in:

   ```
   Unhandled Exception:

   Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState occurred
   ```

Fundamentally here what I'm trying to do:

- Redirect to the LoginPage if the user is not logged in
- Display a "HomePage" (here SampleWithAppResources) once the user is logged in.

By the way, I've the exact same error in the Action when trying to present first the LoginPage, then replacing the `App.Current.MainPage`

If any of you have a clue on how to do this, it would be really helpful.

Comment: So, problem solved, in Xamarin.Forms: android likes only PopModal in Actions... So I make something dirty for android like: MasterDetail.Detail = new MainPage(); MasterDetail.Detail.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage()); in the constructor and then MasterDetail.Detail.PopModalAsync() in the action...

Comment: And I dropped the Xamarin.Auth plugin which was doing weird stuffs and preventing me from doing things like persisting the user's auth...